# How to get autoincrement to work in SQLite based on condition of another column?

Tags: sqlite

I am constructing an SQLite database to locally store messages between users for an app that I am designing. I know that I can create a table that houses my desired object attributes as such:

```
CREATE TABLE messages (userIDs string, message string, sender string, messageNumber integer);
```

I would like to have the `messageNumber` auto increment for each successive input that I insert into the `messages` table. I think I can do that as follows (correct me if I am wrong):

```
CREATE TABLE messages (userIDs string, message string, sender string, messageNumber integer primary key autoincrement)
```

What this command does, though, is increase the `messageNumber` for every single input into the table. If I have 5 objects, it will have autoincremented up to 5. However, what I would like is for this autoincrement to be conditional. I would like it to only autoincrement for each `insert into` if the `userIDs` string is the same. If it is a new/different `userIDs` string, then to start a new autoincrement (back at 1) for that group while maintaining the separate autoincrement for the other group. And so on and so on for every new `userIDs` grouped set of objects, they have their own autoincrement values, separated from the others. Is this possible?

Comment: This isn't a feature available in SQLite. You'll need to code the logic into your application. Also, the AUTOINCREMENT keyword doesn't do what it sounds like it does. See the [docs](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html).

Comment: @glibdud how do I go about coding that kind of logic?

Comment: You have already described the logic: read the largest number for the user, add one.

Comment: And on second thought, you may be able to accomplish this strictly within SQLite using a [trigger](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html).

Comment: @glibdud well thats exactly my question. How do I do that?